# Fill in predefined excel template with the help of tags

Tags: python

I was wondering if it is possible to fill in a predefined excel template, with the help of tags, like in the following simplified example.

[image]

**EDIT:** I'd like to replace the `[TAGS]` with data out of a MySQL database to generate a report (with graphs if possible).

**Retrieving the cell location on the basis of its content might be all I need.**

Comment: What kind of answer are you looking for ? One that automates filling of excel sheet via python ?

Comment: You could create the csv directly from python without any excel template

Comment: You really need to clarify what you are looking for. There are no official Python modules used to manipulate excel files - although there are a few around (I haven't tried them). The easiest way to manipulate excel files is to instead use CSV files which Excel can read. But I'm not sure that's what you're looking for. Edit: [Here is the documentation on the CSV module](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/csv.html)

Comment: I'd like to replace the `[TAG]` with data out of a database to generate a report

Comment: Can you show us what format the database would be in? XML, JSON, CSV, TXT?

Comment: Raw data from a MySQL database.

Comment: Well, you could use xlrd to read and xlwt to write to an xls(be aware that it's not xlsx). However, I'm not sure if you will loose some of the nice/fancy formatting on the way. Problem of proprietary formats....

Comment: Do you actually need to use [TAG] formatting instead of cell position?

Comment: Using the tags makes it possible the have multiple versions of a document without needing a different script

Comment: As long as they're not massive it should be possible to loop through them and see which tags you find with some RegEx. I think is doable as long as you don have too much colours and formatting. I believe the module is supposed to respect them where they are, but I cannot guaranteed. I'd like to hear from you if you do some experiment with it and see if works. Personally, I've used them for read and write, but never for both at the same time.